# Imported data into Big Query but can only access the 'table' via job history and can't see it in datasets

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I've imported some data into Big Query, however I can only query the table from Job History but can't seem to add it as a dataset.

What do I need to do in order to convert this as a dataset?

[image: Table info]

How I imported the data: It was done via a third party app in which had access to my Google Analytics (StitchData).

Here are some more additional import details. 
[image: Additional import details]

Comment: You should describe how you did the "import" part. [Most ways of loading data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_with_schema_auto-detection) to a table requires you to specify a dataset beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, "Destination table" should be in format: [DATASET].[TABLE].
Also "Table Info"."Table ID" should have same info.

Guess you already have a dataset, just need a way to see it.

If so, [this video](https://youtu.be/fwTOXizp2_g?t=84) may help you to locate "dataset" in BigQuery Classic UI.